# cv::imread run much faster if I read the same images again with multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

Recently I want to process a lot of images in my folders, to make things faster, I decided to give multithread a try. I wrote something like this

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentMap>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    QDirIterator directories("some_img",
                             QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot,
                             QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    QStringList path;
    while(directories.hasNext()){
        path.push_back(directories.filePath());
        directories.next();
    }
    qDebug()<<"file size : "<<path.size();
    std::atomic<size_t> size = 0;
    auto compute_hash = [&](QString const &name)
    {
        auto const img = cv::imread(name.toStdString());
        if(!img.empty()){
            ++size;
            //in real case, I would do something at here
        }
    };
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    QtConcurrent::blockingMap(path, compute_hash);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    qDebug()<<"elapsed : "<<
               std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();        
}
```

At the first time, it cost me 84046364us to read all of the images from disk, the cpu usage is lower than 15% in first time.

At the second time(Close and restart the program), it only took me 5493552us to read all of the images from disk, the cpu usage raise over 90% this time.Performance is better than the first time about 15 times.

I give intelTBB a try, it has the same issues too. Do anyone know the reason behind this?How could I make the image loading as fast as the second time?Thanks

Comment: It seems normal to me, that's what multithread do.

Comment: Caching. Your image was already in memory, it didnt need to fetching it from disk

Comment: Sounds like those images are being cached.

Comment: There are over 1000 images(one image around 2.8 MBytes), I think the cache is not big enough for those images.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the cache can hold all of them, even if only a couple of hundred images are cached it would still be faster.